# Multibib: how to reset references counter?

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, subdividing, multibib

Im using a complex template to write my document. It is old and I'm having a problem. I have two separate reference list, "Internet References" and "Literature". The problem is that the references counter "[3]" on "internet References" always starts with number 3 and it should start from 1 "[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Rw1.jpg)". The template uses `multibib` package.
My biblio files are: `weblinks.bib` and `literature.bib` (main file is `literature.bib`).
I digged in all files of my project and can not find any counter that I can reset, so I assume that is some kind of "internal" counter.

Anyone knows how to reset that special counter?

In main file `Diploma_Thesis.tex`:

```
% For the two different reference lists ...
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{weblink}{Internet References}
.
.
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literature}
\label{lit}
\bibliography{literature}
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
% the style of bibliography
% start a new page

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Internet References}
\label{wlit}
\bibliographyweblink{weblinks}
\bibliographystyleweblink{abbrv}
\newpage
```

The result in Literature section on PDF:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to delete aux files?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Would you be reluctant to switch to BibLaTeX?

Comment: Sigur: I deleted all aux file in my project but it keeps starting at index 3.

Comment: Corentin: I would change but as I said it is a complex and old template (which  use to write my Master Thesis) and it seems to me to be hard to do. If you can give me some hints I would be glad!

Comment: Probably `\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}` is what you need.

Comment: egreg: with your tip now it works!!! thanks a lot.

Comment: @egreg Same procedure as every worthy comment. ;-)

Answer (score 16):

The package `multibib` provides an option just for that:

```
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
```