# citation renumbering in LaTeX

Tags: citing

I am writing my thesis and came to a problem that I have no idea how to solve it. The problem is explained as following:

1. My thesis has a TOC and LOF and LOT.
2. As some of the figures are referenced to sources their citation were appeared in the LOF.
3. I used `\caption[text in LOF]{text in caption \cite{author:20xx}}` and the numbers are disappeared from the LOF.
4. However, in the chapter one of my diss., the first reference is numbered to [14], which is totally not desired.

**My question:** Is there any way to reset the number of citation from chapter one? I also tried `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` in my config file.

regards
AM

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Maybe your question ist related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97888/124842)

Comment: I am not sure what I did to my bibliography but It is now working correctly, thanks to you both for your helpful comments.

Comment: The figures and tables which were referenced to some sources, mislead the text bibliography and start the numbering from that figure in TOC, LOF and so on. If any body needs the detailed correction please let me know.